# Opening non-default browser with lite-server in angular2 quick start guide

Tags: node.js, angular, launching

Having followed the TypeScript version of the [Angular 2 Quick Start guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), I was wondering if it is possible, and if so how to configure the lite-server to launch a browser other than the default.

It seems lite-server will take command line args, served to it via `yargs.argv`.  And it seems `yargs` will attempt to parse command line args based on fairly common standards (i.e. If a token begins with a `--`, it represents an argument name, otherwise an argument value) to obtain `argv`.  lite-server will attempt to use the `open` property that it gets from `argv`, which is ultimately what launches the browser via [one of the of the node packages that launches processes]. node-open? xdg -open? Not sure, not really as important to me right now as long as my assumption (based on looking at several of these process launchers) is correct, that they all optionally take an argument defining the process to launch.  If omitted, the default browser would be used since the file type to open is html, which is what happens.

If all that is correct, or at least the gist  of it, then it seems I just need to specify `--open chrome`, for example (assuming chrome is in my `PATH` - working on a win machine btw), at the end of the `lite` command defined in `package.json`.

So something like...

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "lite:c": "lite-server --open chrome",
    "lite:f": "lite-server --open firefox ",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
},
```

I apologize if this seems inane, but I won't be at a computer where I can test this for a few days, and I need to know if I have the answer and can stop researching this :). Thanks!

Comment: You may want to configure this globally, you can find my instructions in the answer on this question (as well as clarification for what's happening). http://stackoverflow.com/a/42797387/124486

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Recent changes (@2.1.0) let you set your configs, including browser(s), via `bs-config.json`:

```
{
  "browser": "chrome"
}
```

or

```
{
  "browser": ["chrome","firefox"]
}
```

If you want to set up separate scripts for each broswer you can do the following in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "lite:ff": "lite-server --c bs-firefox.json",
    "lite:c": "lite-server --c bs-chrome.json",
    "lite:ie": "lite-server --c bs-ie.json",
    "lite:all": "lite-server --c bs-all.json"
  }
}
```

While it's not the best solution since you have to copy and maintain your config  in multiple files, it seems to be what is intended by the lite-server maintainer. Here's the current [lite-server.js](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/blob/fda1debc983eb3e0490c3bdcf2074401ad74d4d1/lib/lite-server.js) file for reference.

Comment: Thank you! I have been working on other projects, and had not had a chance to followup with this, nor have I verified your answer yet. However, I am aware that there was a change in the works and this looks inline with the issue on github, so I have changed this to the accepted answer.

Comment: These should be .js rather than .json extentions for the configuration.                  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"lite-server --c bs-dev.js\" ",
    "prod": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"lite-server --c bs-prod.js\" ",
  }

Comment: On Mac OS X, I needed to create a bs-config.json file with this content:

{
  "browser": "google chrome"
}

Comment: Just one clarification: The bs-config.json file should be in the root of your project or basically in the same folder as your package.json.

Comment: I believe it should be { "browser": "google chrome" } not { "browser": "chrome" }. macOS.

Answer (score 5):

For MacOS, I had to use the case sensitive value in the "bs-config.json" file:

```
{
  "browser": "Google Chrome"
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. using MacOS, I first added "browser":"chrome" in bs-config.json, which didn't work. (i got the following error msg: [Browsersync]Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false))

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

The `lite-server` project has been updated to incorporate configurable browser selection.  I'm only leaving this for historical purposes, and support ender's answer.

---

The creator of `lite-server` [has been looking to address the issue](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/1) of configuring all `browser-sync` options in some standard way (`.rc` file suggested).  So this question and answer may be obsolete by the time you read it.

---

**Thank you Sasxa** for pointing this out...

> `lite-server` is actually using `browser-sync` ...

This was critical in coming up with a solution for this particular problem (it's a little embarrassing that I had overlooked or written off as trivial `var sync = require('browser-sync').create();` ... `sync.init()`).

However, that answer will not work as is because this...

> ... so you should be able to use `--browser` [CLI command](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/) for that.
>
> `"lite:c" : "lite-server --browser chrome --open local"`

...doesn't work out of the box.  As it turns out, `lite-server` is not doing anything with the `browser` argument that `yargs` is used to parse out.  I had almost edited Sasxa's answer, but decided it diverged too much, in that you really can't use the `browser-sync` CLI.  `lite-server` is already using the `browser-sync` API.  In particular, [`init()`](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/api/#api-init) is being called, and the [`browser`](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-browser) option needs to be specified there.  There is a complete disconnect between the Angular 2 Quick start guide's `package.json` and `browser-sync` in regards to the `browser` command line arg.

---

### The fix:

So inspired by Sasxa's answer, the `browser` argument will be passed to `yargs.argv`, with value `chrome`.

`lite-server.js` would have to be modified to pass it along to `browser-sync`.  This can be added as a property on the `options` object...

```
var options =
  {
    openPath: openPath,
    files: argv.files ? argv.files : [
      openPath + '/**/*.html',
      openPath + '/**/*.css',
      openPath + '/**/*.js'
    ],
    baseDir: argv.baseDir || './',
    fallback: '/' + openPath + '/index.html',
    browser: argv.browser || "default" // add this line, ~line 24
  };
```

Then, when browser-sync's `init()` is called, specify the `browser` option.

```
sync.init({
  port: argv.port || 3000,
  server: {
    baseDir: options.baseDir,
    middleware: [
      log(),
      historyFallback({ index: options.fallback })
    ]
  },
  files: options.files,
  browser: options.browser // add this line, ~line 49
});
```

Now, returning to the Angular 2 Quick Start `package.json`, the following argument values can be used for the `browser` argument:

- `chrome`
- `firefox`
- `iexplore`

like so...

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",

    "lite": "lite-server",
    "lite:c": "lite-server --browser \"chrome\"",
    "lite:ff": "lite-server --browser \"firefox\"",
    "lite:ie": "lite-server --browser \"iexplore\"",
    "lite:garbage": "lite-server --browser \"garbage\"",

    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite:c\" ",

    "//": "start default browser:",
    "//": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "//": "start chrome:",
    "//": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite:c\" ",
    "//": "start firefox:",
    "//": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite:ff\" ",
    "//": "start ie:",
    "//": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite:ie\" ",
    "//": "if you want to see an invalid browser arg value, try...",
    "//": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite:garbage\" "
},
```

---

### Some final thoughts

You may need to use `"google chrome"` as the `browser` value to get chrome to actually launch.  I needed to use `"chrome"`, whereas the [docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-browser) say "google chrome"...

> // Open the site in Chrome
>
> `browser: "google chrome"`
>
> // Open the site in Chrome & Firefox
>
> `browser: ["google chrome", "firefox"]`

The *command line* `open` argument *is being used by `lite-server`*, as part of the `startPath` that is passed to `browser-sync`.  `browser` seems canonically correct for specifying the desired browser to launch, since it is ultimately being used by that name in `browser-sync`.  Also, in regards to this, Sasxa's answer was incorrect in assuming `--open local` would make it to `browser-sync` unscathed.  That will actually cause a corrupted path, because it is consumed by lite-server, and transformed into a path like `\local\index.html`, instead of `\.\index.html` if left unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

`lite-server` is actually using `browser-sync`, so you should be able to use `--browser` [CLI command](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/) for that.

```
"lite:c" : "lite-server --browser chrome --open local"
```

Comment: Having looked at the docs for browser-sync I'm confident you're correct.  I think this line from the github readme threw me off..."works by injecting an asynchronous script tag (<script async>...</script>".  I assumed this was the sole purpose of the package, and it took place after the browser had already launched. +1 for now, but I'm fairly certain I'll accept this answer as soon as I verify.

Comment: brsync is great, one of the best live reload packages I worked with (it can  sync screens across many devices/browsers you use to view your pages). If you use it as server you don't have to add any scripts to your code, but there's a snippet to add if you're serving files with different server (I use wamp and google app engine dev server) and still use live-reload feature.

Comment: Thanks again, but this did not work as is.  It lead me in the right direction.  The +1 still stands because you're the only one that responded and I'm sure your tip saved me some time.  For reference I am posting an answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

Make a file name "bs-config.json" in your project folder and add below code to that file:

```
{
"browser": ["chrome","firefox"]         //to make chrome to default browser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows (and Mac) newbies (and not so newbies :):
Your first impulse may be to look for 'bs-config.json' within your project directory. You won't find it.  You need to create a file ***under the root project directory*** and name it **bs-config.json**. Within it you specify the browser of your preference, per the above answer -i.e.,: {"browser": "chrome"
}

The reason being is that file **lite-server.js** looks for the above config file; if it doesn't find it, it uses lite-server defaults, defaulting Internet Explorer on Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Debian/Ubuntu and `update-alternatives`

I was able to confirm that you can change this process globally through this [command here](https://askubuntu.com/a/414808). Currently `lite-server` uses [`browser-sync`](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/) which uses [`opn`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn) which [bundles its own copy of a `xdg-open`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn/blob/b792b3bc3ad8a1f1090bffc5ef8f7e01f4a24697/index.js#L52). You can configure this with,

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

I found it preferable. It takes effect on all angular2 examples, and persists for the rest of the OS too. You can also make the links open in incognito (instructions in the link above).