# Angular Quickstart: Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: angular, typescript, browser-sync, lite-server, node8.4

I cloned [Angular quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart). then I ran `npm install`, and then `npm start`. This is what I got.

```
$ npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
> tsc -p src/


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
> concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"

[1] 
[1] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
[1] > lite-server -c=bs-config.json
[1] 
[0] 
[0] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build:watch /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
[0] > tsc -p src/ -w
[0] 
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: 
[1]    { baseDir: 'src',
[1]      middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ],
[1]      routes: { '/node_modules': 'node_modules' } } }
[1] [Browsersync] Access URLs:
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://192.168.2.159:3000
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.2.159:3001
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1] [Browsersync] Serving files from: src
[1] internal/child_process.js:325
[1]     throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
[1]     ^
[1] 
[1] Error: spawn EACCES
[1]     at _errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
[1]     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:325:11)
[1]     at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:493:9)
[1]     at module.exports (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/opn/index.js:75:24)
[1]     at Object.open (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:186:9)
[1]     at Object.openBrowser (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:165:23)
[1]     at EventEmitter.service:running (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/internal-events.js:42:23)
[1]     at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
[1]     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:7)
[1]     at /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/browser-sync.js:260:19
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR!
[1]  errno 1
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve: `lite-server -c=bs-config.json`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     /home/ecarroll/.npm/_logs/2017-09-05T19_38_23_635Z-debug.log
[1] npm run serve exited with code 1
[0] 14:38:25 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

contents of `/home/ecarroll/.npm/_logs/2017-09-05T19_38_23_635Z-debug.log`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'serve' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.0
3 info using node@v8.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~preserve: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/.bin:/home/ecarroll/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ecarroll/.fzf/bin
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: CWD: /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
10 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'lite-server -c=bs-config.json' ]
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve: `lite-server -c=bs-config.json`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart
16 verbose Linux 4.10.0-33-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v8.4.0
19 verbose npm  v5.4.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve: `lite-server -c=bs-config.json`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Versions,

```
node --version
v8.4.0

npm --version
5.4.0

tsc --version
Version 2.5.2
```

If I try to exec `lite-server` manually, it's also failing

```
node ./node_modules/lite-server/bin/lite-server -c bs-config.json 
** browser-sync config **
{ injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: 
   { baseDir: 'src',
     middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     routes: { '/node_modules': 'node_modules' } } }
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.2.159:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.2.159:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: src
internal/child_process.js:325
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:325:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:493:9)
    at module.exports (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/opn/index.js:75:24)
    at Object.open (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:186:9)
    at Object.openBrowser (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js:165:23)
    at EventEmitter.service:running (/home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/internal-events.js:42:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at /home/ecarroll/code/angular/quickstart/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/browser-sync.js:260:19
```

Comment: Might check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005867/gulp-error-spawn-eacces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Easy and best solution

1. Update `npm` so the problem doesn't happen again `sudo npm update -g npm`
2. Run this from the directory of the angular project.

   ```
   find ./node_modules/ -type f -name xdg-open -exec chmod a+x {} \;
   ```

   This gives `xdg-open` `+x` which permits `npm start` to open the browser to the applications url without throwing an exception.

## Disable Opening the browser

Based on the suggestion in the comments by Tyler Christian, and similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33353944/124486), there is a file called `bs-config.json`

Change it from this,

```
{
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

by adding the open parameter to this,

```
{
  "open": false,
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

I will investigate now as to why this cryptic error is generated, and what the underlying problem is.

## The bug, identified

**And, here is the problem -- it's in the package [`opn`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn/issues/70). Thanks goes out to me for explaining how [this error prone process works on March 14, 2017.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797387/124486) Evan Carroll rocks.**

- [Patch created and submitted](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn/pull/71) (**update** patch rejected)